# createShadowRoot vs attachShadow

Tags: javascript, polymer, shadow-dom

The mozilla developer doc says that `createShadowRoot` is deprecated in favor of `attachShadow` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/createShadowRoot) though the link to attach shadow goes to 404. W3C draft also indicates that the correct way would be `attachShadow`, [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/#shadow-dom-example). Again W3C issue list suggests another way of creating AND attaching shadow roots for reusability and to make hosts mutable, right [here](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/129#issuecomment-118205891).

I am simply confused. Should I go for it, should I abandon it, or should I go for 3rd parties like Polyfill and [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org); though the latter actually using something named Shady DOM which is just looking at the problems that Shadow DOM addresses from (not just different but) a complete opposite angle.

It will be much appreciated if a practical solution for the transition time to a final standard could be discussed.

Comment: Should you go for it? Who knows? What exactly do you need this for, if it's just for playing around, almost no browsers supports this anyway, so go for it, and if it's for production, you should stay far far away for now, until there actually is a spec, and at least some support for shadow DOM's

Comment: @adeneo Thanks! I intended to start building a new web app, given the complexity of plugins and their negative effects on each other, it seemed a good solution to at least protect my codes from plugins from now on using encapsulation provided by shadow dom. Seeing the state of the draft vs practice made me confused.
As a temporary fix I made an alias of attachShadow. But I don't know what to expect in a long run and couldn't find anything in conventional search, so here I am seeking answers in SO.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Polymer you shouldn't need to bother. Polymer provides it's own API, and polyfills browser differences.
If you don't want to use Polymer, you can still use the `web_components` polyfills and benefit from the browser abstraction.

Shady DOM is a polyfill that is optimized for performance instead of perfect browser abstraction. You have to use Polymers API for DOM manipulation to actively enable Polymer to do the extra work.

You can enable full Shadow DOM (see https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/settings.html for details). This might be slower on browsers without native shadow DOM support (especially Safari mobile) but is a "nearly perfect" polyfill where you don't even need to use Polymers API because the "normal" API is patched by the polyfills.